# Am I able to refresh diagnostics on settings change in Roslyn

Tags: roslyn

Let's say that I've created a diagnostic analyzer that shows warning if an `IfStatementSyntax` does not have opening and closing braces. Also, my Visual Studio extension has setting allowing to the user to disable such kind of diagnostics. What I am trying to achieve is to invalidate the current diagnostics when this setting has been change because they might be inadequate. Am I able to do this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there is no such mechanism at the time being.
More information can be found [here](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/572015).